# Asp.net core keep using the expired certificate

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ssl-certificate

Recently, my localhost certificate is expired, I have gone to "sertmgr.msc" remove all localhost certificate and restart the VS and add a new localhost certificate to windows.
But when am I running my application again, still use the old expired certificate not the new one, does anyone know how to fix that?
I have already run the command show below.

```sh
dotnet dev-certs https --clean
dotnet dev-certs https --trust
```

[Expired Cert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRVNq.png)
[Cert In Cert Manage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QE2Kj.png)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I managed to hack my way around this issue:

1. Before you do anything, clean the old certificate and generate a new trusted one.

   ```
   dotnet dev-certs https --clean
   dotnet dev-certs https --trust
   ```
2. And if the process above fails, [manually remove the certificates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#windows---certificate-not-trusted) before retrying the clean/trust commands.
3. Get the User Secrets ID of the Web Application you're having trouble with. Search for UserSecrets.UserSecretsIdAttribute(" in your project folder and take the GUID.
4. Go to `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\UserSecrets` and open the folder containing the GUID of the problematic project you are struggling with and leave it open.
5. Create a new Asp .Net Core project, get its `secrets` GUID, go to the corresponding secret folder (`%APPDATA%\Microsoft\UserSecrets\GUID`), and open the file `secrets.json`. You should see something like this

   ```
   {
     "Kestrel:Certificates:Development:Password": "8353f2ec-3cc0-4052-9776-9585b6abd346"
   }
   ```
6. Copy that setting from the newly created project `secrets.json` and use it to override the development password on the `secrets.json` of the broken project

This way, I've managed to get my old project to use the newly generated certificate. It is hacky, but it works

Comment: Awesome, it's working. I have just deleted the section "Kestrel:Certificates:Development:Password" in the "%APPDATA%\Microsoft\UserSecrets" and everything is fine. Thanks, really help.

Comment: removing the UserSecrets folder was the trick
many thanks

Comment: I also solved when I deleted "Kestrel:Certificates:Development:Password", I believe delete UserSecrets folder also works.

Comment: Step 3 - the user secrets Id should be in the .csproj file. Right click project -> Edit Project File to open it.

Comment: @GuilhermedeJesusSantos correctly pointed out, that deleting the "Kestrel:Certificates:Development:Password" also works to resolve this problem, at least in  my case.

Comment: Thank you @Pedro Yan Ornelas. I was having issues with this, and your mention of UserSecrets saved me day.

Comment: Glad to hear buddy :)

Comment: Its been a while but I thought I'd add, I didnt have any luck with this until I ran the commands to clean and trust as an administrator.

Comment: Worked for me too. I just deleted the key "Kestrel:Certificates:Development:Password" from relevant file in "%APPDATA%\Microsoft\UserSecrets"

Comment: Yessss, been struggling 2h with this. Thanks man!

Answer (score 9):

For my ASP.NET Core with Angular project on Visual Studio 2022:

```
dotnet dev-certs https --clean
dotnet dev-certs https --trust
dotnet dev-certs https --check
```

I then stopped Visual Studio and deleted the `.key` and the `.pem` files for the project in

```
C:\Users\[your_user]\AppData\Roaming\ASP.NET\Https
```

Comment: deleting .key saved my day. thanks!

Comment: Thank you, that worked! The Angular scaffolding in Visual Studio recreates the .pem and .key files from the current certificate. But it does not seem to check if the cert is expired.

Comment: Worked for me too in a scenario with a vue.js/vite setup

Answer (score 6):

Based on Pedro's answer,

I used:

```
dotnet dev-certs https --clean
dotnet dev-certs https --trust
```

to clean/replace the old certs.

Then I went to:

```
%APPDATA%\Microsoft\UserSecrets
```

And deleted all the folders found there.

Now my application runs without complaining.
Creating a new .net core 6 application and running it didn't create a new folder, so I don't know if it's no-longer required.

Comment: Don't delete all the folders from there! if you have apps that use actual UserSecrets and have some passwords there, those will be deleted. Check what you are deleting first!

Answer (score 3):

I want to provide some context about Pedro's answer on Windows.

Thanks to [this article](https://www.domstamand.com/asp-net-core-kestrelserver-using-wrong-development-ssl-certificate/) and some testing, I found out that the password specified by `Kestrel:Certificates:Development:Password` setting applies to a project dedicated certificate found in `%APPDATA%\ASP.NET\Https`.

**Answer:** When you delete either the password setting or the project certificate, Kestrel starts working as expected, looking for a proper certificate installed with `dotnet dev-certs` command. I think the most convenient is to delete all project certificates from `%APPDATA%\ASP.NET\Https` folder.

This seems to be a Visual Studio problem when the project was created. However, I could not reproduce it with my current version of Visual Studio 2019.

In conclusion, the problem is not about the `dotnet dev-certs` command, but rather about hidden logic on how Visual Studio creates the project and how Kestrel handles certificates.

Comment: I think the most convenient is to delete all project certificates from %APPDATA%\ASP.NET\Https folder. --- worked for me

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with different types of projects:

- ASP.NET Core with Angular template created with VS Code.
- ASP.NET Core Web API created with Visual Studio.

---

When the problem comes with the **ASP.NET Core with Angular** template on Windows, you can try:

1. Stop the application.
2. Open the *File Explorer*.
3. Paste *%APPDATA%\ASP.NET\https* into the address bar and press *enter*.
4. It will navigate automatically to *C:\Users\[your_user]\AppData\Roaming\ASP.NET\Https*
5. Delete the *your_npm_package_name.**pem*** and *your_npm_package_name.**key*** files.

   - *your_npm_package_name*: Is the *name* property value of the *package.json* file of your Angular client app.
6. Open MMC (*Start* > *Run* > *MMC*). Open the *Certificates* Snap-in (*File* > *Add/Remove Snap-in*).
7. Select *My Current Account* when prompted.
8. Under *Certificates - Current User* select the *Personal\Certificates* folder.
9. Locate and select the certificate for *localhost* domain and with the Friendly Name "ASP.NET Core HTTPS development certificate".
10. Delete the *localhost* certificate.
11. Repeat the *localhost* certificate deletion process for al *localhost* certificate with the Friendly Name "ASP.NET Core HTTPS development certificate" under the *Personal\Certificates* folder and the *Trusted Root Certification Authorities\Certificates* folder too.
12. Start your application again.
13. Your application's *pem* and *key* files will be automatically regenerated.

This solution is also valid for other advanced templates like Jason Taylor's Clean Architecture Solution Template.

---

When the problem comes with a **ASP.NET Core Web API** project created with Visual Studio and enabling Docker (not always).

After trying all the alternatives of this question and using the [Generate self-signed certificates with the .NET CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/self-signed-certificates-guide) and [Enforce HTTPS in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl) guides from Microsoft, I found that my expired certificate was located in the *C:\Users[your_user]\AppData\Roaming\ASP.NET\Https* folder with the name *my_api_assembly_name.pfx*.

How did I regenerate my certificate?

1. Stop the application.
2. Open the *File Explorer*.
3. Paste *%APPDATA%\ASP.NET\https* into the address bar and press *enter*.
4. It will navigate automatically to *C:\Users\[your_user]\AppData\Roaming\ASP.NET\Https*
5. Delete the *your_my_api_assembly_name.**pfx***.
6. Open MMC (*Start* > *Run* > *MMC*). Open the *Certificates* Snap-in (*File* > *Add/Remove Snap-in*).
7. Select *My Current Account* when prompted.
8. Under *Certificates - Current User* select the *Personal\Certificates* folder.
9. Locate and select the certificate for *localhost* domain and with the Friendly Name "ASP.NET Core HTTPS development certificate".
10. Delete the *localhost* certificate.
11. Repeat the *localhost* certificate deletion process for al *localhost* certificate with the Friendly Name "ASP.NET Core HTTPS development certificate" under the *Personal\Certificates* folder and the *Trusted Root Certification Authorities\Certificates* folder too.
12. Open your *Windows Terminal* as administrator.
13. Run `dotnet dev-certs https -ep $env:USERPROFILE\AppData\Roaming\ASP.NET\Https\your_api_assembly_name.pfx -p your_user_secrets_id`:

    1. Change *your_my_api_assembly_name* with your own assembly name.
    2. How to retrieve *your_user_secrets_id*?

       1. Open *your_project.csproj* with a text editor (or double-click on the project in Visual Studio Solution Explorer) and look for a node called *UserSecretsId*. Inside this node there is your *your_user_secrets_id*.
       2. Otherwise, if you don't have the *UserSecretsId* node in your project file:

          1. Open the *File Explorer*.
          2. Paste *%APPDATA%\Microsoft\UserSecrets* into the address bar and press *enter*.
          3. It will navigate automatically to *C:\Users\[your_user]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Secrets*
          4. Open the folder called as the GUID of your project (you can get yours inside your *your_solution.sln* file).
          5. Open the *secrets.json* file and find a property called *Kestrel:Certificates:Development:Password*. The value of this property is your *your_user_secrets_id*.
14. Your application's *pfx* file will be automatically regenerated.
15. Run `dotnet dev-certs https --trust`.
16. You will be prompted to install a new certificate for localhost.
17. Click *Yes*.
18. Start your application again.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using IIS Express to host your application. If so, it sounds like you're missing linking the certificate to your application(s) as described in [this blog post](https://improveandrepeat.com/2020/05/how-to-change-the-https-certificate-in-iis-express/):

Go to `C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express` and run the following from the command line, entering the proper port number and the new certificate thumbprint:

```
IisExpressAdminCmd.exe setupsslUrl -url:https://localhost:PORT/ -CertHash:THUMB
```

Comment: Didn't help in my case, since I'm running the application via `dotnet run`. If I manage to fix the issue, I will post it here

Comment: Not IIS, it's console