# Cannot call asp.net core localhost endpoint from console application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, ssl, localhost

Just curious if anyone has struggled with this issue.

I have a console application and try to call an api endpoint, in another Visual Studio instance (asp.net core api project) on `https://localhost:5108`.
It will hang and then  eventually time out after about a minute with `The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception`. If I change the protocol from https to http it hangs and then get a `service unavailable` error.

I have tried removing the certificates and adding the certificates in my personal user store, a process described in these posts.

[Trust the ASP.NET Core HTTPS development](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#trust-the-aspnet-core-https-development-certificate-on-windows-and-macos) and here [Asp.net core keep using the expired certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64618112/asp-net-core-keep-using-the-expired-certificate)

Nothing seems to work, definitely a first for me.

Any suggestions perhaps?

Comment: Is it an option for you to publish the web project (api) to local IIS?  I do this for an .net core api that I develop locally in which another local console application calls.  I then debug both running applications (api and console).  Publishing the .net core api locally made things a lot easier for me for debugging everything.

Comment: Are you able to access this endpoint through browser or Postman? If yes, try to change applicationUrl to be http://

Comment: @BasilKosovan yes thanks. I can call the endpoint from postman so it is possible to simulate the call from the other service. Tried calling http:// (from visual studio) but that hangs and times out with a 503.

Comment: Show the code that you are using for a call,

Comment: Also, you can try to skip the SSL check. If you are using RestSharp it will be ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=
        (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true; if